# Building uEFI bootable ISO and USB for Windows 7 deployment

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, bios, windows-installer, uefi

I have been trying to build up a window's 7 and 2k8 EFI deployment ISO or USB.
But struggling to to even get an ISO to boot from even VMware Workstation EFI implementation. The problem is there is no clear requirement to what the EFI bootloader is looking for, "e.g EFI boot file" even ISO's and USB's that are bootable don't find the required .efi file.

I'd like to know what is the process EFI bootloader follows to boot the EFI file. e.g;

> in a EFI windows system its; `C:\Windows\Boot\EFI\bootmgfw.efi`
>
> From DVD it's; `F:\efi\microsoft\boot\cdboot.efi`
>
> from what people tell me it's on USB; `G:\efi\boot\bootx64.efi (bootmgfw.efi renamed)`

I've been testing on a HP notebook with EFI 2.0 and VMware Workstation 8.0 with .vmx file firmware = "efi"

Answer (score 2):

This Microsoft article covered exactly what you're looking for:

[How to create an ISO image for UEFI platforms for a Windows PE CD-ROM for Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947024)

The instruction line that is fundamentally different for UEFI images is:

```
oscdimg -m -o -u2 -udfver102 -bootdata:2#p0,e,bc:\winpe_x64\etfsboot.com#pEF,e,bc:\winpe_x64\efisys.bin c:\winpe_x64\ISO c:\winpe_x64\winpeuefi.iso
```